# How to change the cursor color in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, color-scheme

I am using SQL Developer with a dark background theme ('classic'), which is really nice. However, the cursor is hard to see, since it has a color (grey?) that is very similar to the background color (blue).

Is there a way to change the color of the cursor?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

In SQL Developer under

Preferences > Code Editor > Caret Behavior > Caret Color

There you can change the color of the cursor.

Source

1. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/09/30-sql-developer-tips-in-30-days-day-3-syntax-highlighting/

Comment: This is the correct answer - the key is recognizing that they call it a "caret" instead of a "cursor".

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check your item background colour and item foreground colour if they have the same settings.
To check this

1. Click on tools (on the menu bar)
2. Click Options
3. Click on Environment
4. Click on fonts and colours
5. Under display items, click on plain text
6. Under item foreground select default
7. Under item background select white
8. Click on Okay.

Comment: This addresses the background color vs. the text color, not the cursor.